# Code not functioning correctly identifying prime numbers in an array

Tags: java

This code is supposed to firstly, run a code that gets the factors of a number, and secondly run a code to check numbers in an array and remove any prime numbers.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayListFunHouse {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int input;
private int keepOnlyCompositeNumbersSize;
private static ArrayList<Integer> onlyCompositeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> keepOnlyCompositeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactorsComposite = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void setInput() {
    System.out.print("Please input the input you want to check the factors of :: ");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the size of the array you wish to find the composite numbers in :: ");
    keepOnlyCompositeNumbersSize = keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int spot = 0; spot < keepOnlyCompositeNumbersSize; spot++) {
        keepOnlyCompositeNumbers.add(keyboard.nextInt());
    }
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactors() {
        for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
        if(input % i == 0 && i!= 1 && i != input) {
            getListOfFactors.add(i);
        }
    }
    return getListOfFactors;
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactorsCompositeList(int number) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0 && i!= 1 && i != number) {
            getListOfFactorsComposite.add(i);
        }
    }
    return getListOfFactorsComposite;
}
public static ArrayList<Integer> keepOnlyCompositeNumbers() {
    for(int i = 0; i < keepOnlyCompositeNumbers.size();i++) {
        if(getListOfFactorsCompositeList(keepOnlyCompositeNumbers.get(i)).isEmpty() == false) {
            onlyCompositeNumbers.add(keepOnlyCompositeNumbers.get(i));
        }
    }
    return onlyCompositeNumbers;
}
public static void print() {
    System.out.println(getListOfFactors);
    System.out.println("Original list");
    System.out.println(keepOnlyCompositeNumbers);
    System.out.println("Composite List");
    System.out.println(onlyCompositeNumbers);
    }
}
```

This is the runner:

```
public class ArrayListFunHouseRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayListFunHouse A = new ArrayListFunHouse();
    A.setInput();
    ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors();
    ArrayListFunHouse.keepOnlyCompositeNumbers();
    ArrayListFunHouse.print();
}

}
```

Input:

```
Array Size: 15
Numbers: 2 6 8 9 10 12 13 15 17 24 55 66 78 77 79
```

Expected output is

```
[6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77]
```

Actual output is

```
[6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77, 79]
```

Comment: My first impression is that you have a very weird mix of static and non-static stuff in your class, for no apparent reason.  But that's not likely to be the problem.

Comment: Your code is hard to read and reason about, because you don't accept parameters and work on static variables. Naming methods exactly like static data members does not help either. Consider a much simpler pipeline: `System.out.println(filterCompositeNumbers(inputs));`, where `filterCompositeNumbers` calls `getFactors()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactorsCompositeList(int number) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0 && i!= 1 && i != number) {
            getListOfFactorsComposite.add(i);
        }
    }
    return getListOfFactorsComposite;
}
```

to

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactorsCompositeList(int number) {
    getListOfFactorsComposite = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0 && i!= 1 && i != number) {
            getListOfFactorsComposite.add(i);
        }
    }
    return getListOfFactorsComposite;
}
```

Basically, you just need to add one line `getListOfFactorsComposite = new ArrayList<Integer>();` in the beginning of the method `getListOfFactorsCompositeList`

**Reason**

You have declared `getListOfFactorsComposite` as an instance field of `List` type. So between the method calls, it is retaining the elements added in the prior method calls. Addition of this line is required to reset the List prior to new use.

Comment: Better yet, make it a local variable instead of a static one.

Comment: But yeah - the problem is that the ArrayList isn't being reset.  Once it finds one composite number, it thinks everything is a composite number because something is in the factor list (even if it was actually left over from a previous number.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand how to pass parameters and how to use objects.

The following code has a method that knows if a number is prime and if that method returns true, then we don't add those numbers to the new list.

It also makes use of an inner class, and I think it's clearer to understand what's happening than in your code.

Note that I removed the `System.out.println("");` calls so your input is like this one:

Input:

```
2 6 8 9 10 12 13 15 17 24 55 66 78 77 79
```

Output:

```
[6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77]
```

As you can see, the output is correct and the code is shorter and clearer

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunHouseRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunHouse funHouse = new FunHouse();
        ArrayList<Integer> userInputList = funHouse.getUserInput(15);
        ArrayList<Integer> listWithoutPrimeNumbers = funHouse.getListWithoutPrimeNumbers(userInputList);
        System.out.println(listWithoutPrimeNumbers);
    }
}

class FunHouse {

    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList <Integer> getUserInput(int size) {
        ArrayList <Integer> userInputList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            userInputList.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        return userInputList;
    }

    public ArrayList <Integer> getListWithoutPrimeNumbers(ArrayList <Integer> userInputList) {
        ArrayList <Integer> listWithoutPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int n : userInputList) {
            if (!isPrime(n)) {
                listWithoutPrimeNumbers.add(n);
            }
        }

        return listWithoutPrimeNumbers;
    }

    public void printList(ArrayList<Integer> listWithoutPrimeNumbers) {
        System.out.println(listWithoutPrimeNumbers);
    }
}
```